# Flutter doctor connection reset by peer

Tags: flutter

what's wrong?
this happend when i run flutter doctor, and i cant't login with firebase

[flutter doctor issue connection reset by peer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giQpU.png)

anyone can help, I have try reset my wifi connection.
I try many method, reset my router, change my ip, I have use vpn, the solution when I try change hotspot

Comment: Can you visit the website in your browser? This is just to check if maybe the website it straight up down in your region.

Comment: I can open any website, only firebase I can't